# How to access json_decode() data after passing through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently writing a simple ajax script to practice my ajax skills, i am submitting form via ajax using **serializeArray()** method i am able to successfully pass it but not able to perform any operation on data.
This is the ajax script i am using currently

```
 var submit_post = $("#submit-post");
 $(submit_post).on('click',function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    {
        method:'POST',
        data:
        {
            form:JSON.stringify($("#emp-post-form").serializeArray())
        },success:function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },dataType:'text'
    })
})
```

In the back end i am handling the data in following way

```
if(isset($_POST['form']))
    {
        $form_data = [];
        $form_data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['form']),true);
        var_dump($form_data);
    }
```

When i var_dump() post data the following is the format of my data

```
   Array
   (

    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => emp-id-list
        [value] => 1248
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => emp-first-name
        [value] => John
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => emp-last-name
        [value] => King
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => title
        [value] => Post title
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => post-content
        [value] => Some Post
    )

    )
```

But how do i use this data for instance if i want echo title name the following code wont work

> echo $_POST['title'];

What should i do next in order to use it ?

PS:I have already succeeded with using **serialize() and then using parse_str()** in php but as i am learning i need answer particular for this question only and not an alternative to it

Comment: You need to tell PHP which name/value you want. So `$form_data[0]['name']` will be "emp-id-list", `$form_data[3]['value']` will be "Post title"

Comment: this is why I don't use serializeArray(), its an annoying structure to work with at the PHP end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the (cumbersome) data structure for `$_POST['form']` provided by `$("#emp-post-form").serializeArray()`, you can transform it server-side to a PHP associative array keyed by the original form-element names :

```
$form_data = array();

if(isset($_POST['form'])) 
{
    $raw_form_data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['form']), true);
    foreach($raw_form_data, true) as $item) {
        $form_data[$item['name']] = $item['value'];
    };
}
```

You now have an array which is directly addressable, in the way you want :

```
echo $form_data['emp-id-list']; // 1248
echo $form_data['emp-first-name']; // John
echo $form_data['emp-last-name']; // King
echo $form_data['title']; // Post title
echo $form_data['post-content']; // Some Post
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the whole process and use `serialize()` to form encode the whole form the same way it gets sent without using ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url:'...',
  method: 'POST',
  data: $("#emp-post-form").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  dataType: 'text'
})
```

Then all the `name`'s from the form elements will be available directly in `$_POST`

```
$title=  $_POST['title'];
$emp_fName = $_POST['emp-first-name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the title, if you know the key you can do

```
$title = $form_data[3]['value'];
```

or if you don't you can loop trough it:

```
foreach($form_data as $input){
    if($input['name'] == 'title'){
        $title = $input['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't seem to know what serializeArray() does. https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ how can the OP use php in the ajax request?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? The ajax call is sent to a php page, the code I added is to be used there, not on the client side.

Comment: Why isn't it a great solution? I dont see a better one that uses serializeArray()